# How to delete edge in gephi?

Tags: gephi

I want to delete an edge in graph window.

I can right-click on a node and delete it from context menu.

I can NOT do this for an edge using Windows or Linux version (0.10.1).

Context menu is 'greyed out'

I feel dumb... it seems that I can't select an edge this way...

[![right-click on edge and get greyed-out context menu][1]][1]

[image: right click on edge]

Comment: Seems perhaps like a bug, I just saw the same thing. Could you post in the forum and see if this is widely known? A workaround is to delete an edge from the _Data laboratory/Edges_

Comment: thank's @yannis-p, I am aware of deleting from table - just seems odd that an obvious and necessary GUI function doesn't work.

Comment: It is odd and it should work. I will submit an error report.